# libsnmp-base breaks the ubuntu upgrade

Tags: 18.04, apt, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

On terminal trying to upgrade `Ubuntu-18.04` to `Ubuntu-20.04LTS` using below commands

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade --yes
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade --yes
```

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade --yes
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Error!
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsnmp-base : Breaks: snmp (< 5.7.3+dfsg-5) but 5.7.3+dfsg-1.8ubuntu3.6 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Have downloaded and installed using `dpkg --force-all -i libsnmp-base_5.7.3+dfsg-1.8ubuntu3.6_all.deb` and `--fix-broken` couldn't help to fix.

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 363 not upgraded.
```

Still resulting same error. Any pointer to fix this error will be helpful.

Comment: Maybe run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: @Algnis, `sudo apt --fix-broken install` couldn't help.

Comment: BTW you need to use `sudo do-release-upgrade` instead of dist upgrade

Comment: @user4948798 Please add the output of `apt-cache policy libsnmp-base snmp` to the question. Do you remember how they were installed?

Answer (score 1):

Aptitude may help you to fix the issue. If it is installed please use it as follows

```
sudo aptitude dist-upgrade
```

to get newest dependencies on existing system and then follow its recommendation for possible solution.

If it is not installed please install it by `sudo apt-get install aptitude` and retry with above command.

And only when all dependency issues are fixed on 18.04 LTS you can run upgrade procedure to 20.04 LTS using `sudo do-release-upgrade` (in GUI) or `update-manager -c` (on desktop) .

Comment: +1 for adding do release upgrade

Comment: @Algnis, @N0rbert, I have uninstalled `snmp` package and succeed with the upgrade. But post reboot server showing black ping colour sreen.  Not sure what had went wrong. Upgrade time didn't face issues.

Comment: @user4948798 This is a completely different question consider [asking a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Sure Algnis. Thanks a lot for the support.